# Add buttons to Leaflet map - MYSQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, leaflet

I have a Leaflet map that shows me information that I added from a query and parse it to that map from MYSQL database. How can I add some buttons to sort the pins via category? I have a table for each category. Thanks! I followed [this](https://www.phpclasses.org/blog/post/284-Create-a-Google-Maps-alternative-with-PHP-and-MySQL-using-the-Leaflet-library.html)